# ios uibutton add target, pass to selector parameters from same view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I'm kind of stuck here...programmatically I'm creating a small form as a subview.  Programmatically I'm adding a confirm button and adding a target to it.  But I want to be able to get the form contents passed to the selector function.  Is this possible?  Looks something like this:

```
Details = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 20, 250, 300)];
Details.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
Details.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
Details.alpha = 0;

UILabel *NameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 25, 75, 20)];
[NameLabel setText:@"Place Name:"];
[NameLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[Details addSubview:NameLabel];

UITextField *NameTV = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135, 25, 110, 20)];
NameTV.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
NameTV.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
[Details addSubview:NameTV];

confirm = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 250, 75, 40)];
[confirm setTitle:@"Set Marker" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[confirm setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
confirm.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
[confirm setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[confirm addTarget:self action:@selector(confirmMarker://add text field data here) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//attach an array to the button???
[Details addSubview:confirm];

- (void) confirmMarker:(NSString)someString{
    NSLog(@"%@", someString);
}
```

My question is the target gets added when the form view is formed...so someString will be empty even if someone writes something and then clicks the button...right?  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks...

Comment: Perhaps this is too late to matter, but the line:

    confirm = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 250, 75, 40)];

..make little sense. Perhaps there was a "UIButton *" prefixing it in the original code, as in:

UIButton *confirm = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 250, 75, 40)];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why do you need to pass it through the selector if you already have access to the value?

```
- (void) confirmMarker:(NSString)someString{
    NSLog(@"%@", NameTv.text);
}
```

A button's preset selector passes itsself as the variable, so what it's sending is this:

```
- (void) confirmMarker:(id)sender{
    // Sender is the button that sent
    NSLog(@"%@", NameTv.text);
}
```

To perform a selector with your own variables, you'd have to do something like this:

```
IMP imp = [ob methodForSelector:selector];
void (*func)(id, SEL, NSString *) = (void *)imp;
func(ob, selector, @"stringToSend");
```

But, if you triggered that with the button, you'd have to get the textView.text in the first place to pass it, so why not just go with method one, oriented for a buttons standard callback:

```
- (void) confirmMarker:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", NameTv.text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The parameter in selector only the sender itself (button in your case). So, you must store needed information somewhere else, ivar, for example.